# OTPublisherSettings *settings = [[OTPublisherSettings alloc] init]; getting Bad receiver type 'int32_t' (aka 'int')

Tags: tokbox

While compiling

```
OTPublisherSettings *settings = [[OTPublisherSettings alloc] init];
```

getting compiler error.

Bad receiver type 'int32_t' (aka 'int')

Using the latest Xcode, happening on all unmodified sample apps, looked in lib headers dir under Pods, Found the OTPublisher.h and OTPublisherKit.h headers, cannot seem to find the OTPublisherSettings class. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a fresh install of sample apps with pod install without any errors. Did you see any issues when you were trying to install the SDK using cocoapods. What SDK version are you using ?